# Move files that contain selected characters in checkedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

I have a funtion that split documents between folders. In checkedListBox1 are loaded filenames and checkedListBox2 is a list of folders.

checkedListBox1 will store only first ten charachters of file names (I can't change this, it has to show only first 10), and some files will be named like XXXXXXXXXX.INVOICE or something else XXXXXXXXXX.ASDASD etc. I need to move all files that contain that XXXXXXXXXX first charachters in name to selected folder. Can I do that? My function below:

```
private void materialButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This button will split documents checked in checkedlistbox1 that contains selected charachters in their names between folders in checkedlistbox2. Each folder will get an equal number of files. Each folder will get different files.
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie wybrano plików");
        }
        else if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie wybrano folderów");
        }
        else
        {
            string folderPath = textBox1.Text;
            string workerFolder = textBox4.Text;
            string folderName = checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string folderPath2 = workerFolder + "\\" + folderName;
            int filesPerFolder = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count / checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count;
            int filesLeft = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count % checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count;
            int fileIndex = 0;
            foreach (string folder in checkedListBox2.CheckedItems)
            {
                string folderPath3 = workerFolder + "\\" + folder;
                for (int i = 0; i < filesPerFolder; i++)
                {
                    string filePath = folderPath + "\\" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[fileIndex];
                    string filePath2 = folderPath3 + "\\" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[fileIndex];
                    File.Move(filePath, filePath2);
                    fileIndex++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < filesLeft; i++)
            {
                string filePath = folderPath + "\\" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[fileIndex];
                string filePath2 = folderPath2 + "\\" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[fileIndex];
                File.Move(filePath, filePath2);
                fileIndex++;
            }
            //moved files will be removed from the checkedlistbox
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Zakończono");
    }
```

It works great but only if I show full file names in checkedListBox1 :c

Comment: Did you know, you're allowed to rename controls after you drop them on a form...

Comment: Use Path.Combine to build paths, not string concat of "\\"